# How to concatenate multiple values into one column result

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables:

**teacher**

```
+------------+-------------+
|ID          |Name         |
+------------+-------------+
|1           |teacher1     |
|2           |teacher2     |
|3           |teacher3     |
+------------+-------------+
```

**teaches**

```
+------------+-------------+
|teacher_ID  |specialty    |
+------------+-------------+
|1           |specialty1   |
|1           |specialty2   |
|2           |specialty1   |
|3           |specialty5   |
|3           |specialty8   |
|3           |specialty2   |
+------------+-------------+
```

what I am trying to do is: I want a query that can get me the following:

```
+--------------+------------------------------------------+
|teacher_name  |specialties                               |
+--------------+------------------------------------------+
|teacher1      |specialty1, specialty2                    |
|teacher2      |specialty1                                |
|teacher3      |specialty5, specialty8, specialty2        |
+--------------+------------------------------------------+
```

so I want the specialties of each teacher to be concatenated as above in a column's value. Is this even possible to make using MySQL? if so, Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `GROUP_CONCAT` here:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.Name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t2.specialty) AS specialties
FROM teacher t1
LEFT JOIN teaches t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.teacher_ID
GROUP BY
    t1.ID,
    t1.Name;
```

Comment: @GauravKandpal I agree.

Answer (score 0):

use `group_concat()`

```
select Name as teacher_name,group_concat(specialty) as specialties
from teacher a inner join teaches b
on a.id=b.teacher_id
group by b.teacher_id,name
```

Comment: could you please clarify to me on what does `a` and `b` stands for?

Comment: @jes, it's a alias for tablename